# Knob and worm gear open windows

Tags: windows

Can you help me identify or suggest what you'd refer to this type of window that has a rotation handle powering a worm gear that drives the rod to open or close the window?

[image]

Basically, what do you call this kind of window, as opposed to, e.g. double hung etc.

Answer (score 5):

A window hinged at the side is called a casement window.

More specifically, that is a slide hinge, manual, sector crank casement window.

Different manufacturers may have a different name for the 'slide hinge' style. Its purpose is to allow easy cleaning of the outside of the pane.

It's 'manual' because you turn the crank by hand. Some industrial buildings have motorized window cranks.

I'll take your word for it that it has a worm drive. Mine have little pinion gears. If the mechanism includes a member that looks like a partial gear wheel attached to a lever, that's a 'sector crank'.

If you're searching or shopping for this kind of window, don't bother with the 'worm drive' and 'sector crank' terms as these vary with manufacturer choice. Use the terms 'casement' and 'slide hinge' to find these kinds of windows.

Comment: There's also handedness, (right or left opening or swing) though I can't recall if it's from inside or out. Same thing, hinged at the top, is an awning window - "casement and awning" are often grouped in window catalogs.